# Why does the execution change after adding second half of the code?

Tags: python

I am facing difficulty while writing a code for testing for a pangram (a string that contains all 26 alphabets at least once).

When executed based on first part as follows:

```
def ispangram(x):
    alphabet="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
    for i in alphabet:
        if i in x.lower():
            return True
```

The code works fine.

But if I add the else condition:

```
def ispangram(x):
    alphabet="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
    for i in alphabet:
        if i in x.lower():
            return True
        else i not in x.lower():
            return False
```

The code returns every input as a valid pangram.

Could someone please help me understand what is going wrong here?

Comment: I'm not sure your code is correct: `else` in Python doesn't take a condition (`elif` does). Besides, a condition is not even necessary here, since there is no third option. Please check the code example in your question, and update it as necessary.

Comment: You don't need the condition for the else just `else` will do, You also don't particularly need the else

Comment: Your first code block (which you say works fine) is incorrect: `ispangram("a")` will return `True`, but "a" is definitely not a pangram.

Comment: Thank you for the response.  Surely helps me understand better.. :)

Answer (score 2):

You aren't checking every letter in the alphabet. You are only checking if the word contains the letter `a`. Let's examine the control flow

```py
def is_pangram(x):
    x = x.lower()
    alphabet="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"

    # we begin iteration here
    for i in alphabet:
        # we check if the letter is in the word
        if i in x:
            # we return! This will stop execution at the first True
            # which isn't always the case
            return True
        else:
            # we return again! since we've covered all cases, you will
            # only be checking for a
            return False
```

To fix this, you can do one of two things. Using a loop, you can just check if letters are *not* in `x`, returning `False` if they are not, and returning `True` at the end:

```py
def is_pangram(x):
    x = x.lower()
    alphabet="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"

    for i in alphabet:
        if i not in x:
            return False

    # this means we made it through the loop with no breaks
    return True
```

Alternatively, you can use the `all` operator to check if all of the letters in the alphabet are in the word, which returns `True`, otherwise it returns `False`

```py
def is_pangram(x):
    x = x.lower()
    alphabet="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz"
    return all(i in x for i in alphabet)
```

Comment: Another alternative: `set(alphabet).issubset(x.lower())`

Comment: @HeapOverflow very true, but for this exercise, given that OP is struggling with control flow in loops, I felt keeping the answer in that spirit was a bit better. For a more pythonic approach, membership testing with sets is preferable

Comment: @C.Nivs Thanks a lot.. This response is quite elaborate and helpful for a beginner.

Comment: @HeapOverflow I have taken a note of your response. It will be helpful as I improve. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Your first function will return true for any string that contains any letter.  You need to verify that *each* letter is in your input string:

```
import string

def ispangram(x):
    x = x.lower()
    for c in string.ascii_lowercase:
        if c not in x:
            # a letter is not in the input string, so the input string is not a pangram
            return False

    # if we got here, each letter is in the input string
    return True
```

Comment: Thanks @Billy. This helps.